# How to let Android user to decide whether to answer a call or not?

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm writing a small app where I don't want the current activity to automatically switch to the phonecall app upon an incoming call.
I would like the user to decide whether to do it or not from my app UI.

I know I can listen to state changes in the telephony but I don't know how to prevent from the phonecall app to take focus.

Comment: Android can't let an app do this and stay a viable phone platform.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but janm's comment is simply false (despite the upvotes it's getting). Android does let non-root third party developers override this behavior and as far as I can tell, Android is still a viable phone platform.