# Android > Create telephony app that doesn't switch to phone app on incoming call

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Have a working simple telephony application that dials out a hardwired # and also receives incoming calls. But on incoming calls my device (Nexus5) switches to the built in phone application.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening from a coding perspective?

similar question but no answer
[How to let Android user to decide whether to answer a call or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744720/how-to-let-android-user-to-decide-whether-to-answer-a-call-or-not)

From what little I know about rooting, it should be possible to override this default Behaviour

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1

Comment: Definitely a coding question, will edit my question

Comment: What priority did you use in your BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: hichris123, thanks will need to investigate whether any of those solutions work with 4.4 kitkat

Comment: KitKat is a weird one. I wouldn't be surprised if smspopup stopped working as intended on KitKat. https://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/